# sharing gem repository b/w different JRuby versions

Tags: jruby

What is the best way to share gem repository between different JRuby versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recent versions of RubyGems searches `$HOME/.gem/jruby/1.8`. You can verify this with

```
jruby -S gem env
```

and look for `GEM PATHS`.

Comment: Is there any way to make $HOME/.gem/jruby/1.8 default gem location? So if I run "gem install rails" it will put the rails gems into that location?

Comment: I don't think there is a mechanism for that right now. If you feel that is important, please file a ticket at http://bugs.jruby.org. Thanks.